# Converting JSON into Python data frame

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a file containing JSON that looks like the following:

```
{"CompanyXYZ": [
      {"EmployeeList": [
          {"ID": 1557, "LocID": 335, "LineList": [
              {"ProgID": 15, "Late": 288,
                "ProjList": [
                  {"ProjID": 55, "NumInTeam": 5},
                  {"ProjID": 66, "NumInTeam": 3}
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {"ID": 3058, "LocID": 777, "LineList": [
              {"ProgIDID": 62, "Late": 20, "ProjList": [
                  {"ProjID": 62, "NumInTeam": 7 }
                ]
              },
              { "ProgID": 58, "Late": 21, "ProjList": [
                  {"ProjID": 58, "NumInTeam": 8 }
                ]
              },
              {"ProgID": 38, "Late": 15, "ProjList": [
                  {"ProjID": 38, "NumInTeam": 18}
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to load it into a Python 3.6 data frame using
json.load, json.loads, read_json
but all I get is a matrix with one index value (0), one column header (CompanyXYZ), and one data entry (a dictionary containing dictionaries and/or lists capturing all the data).

I am trying to get this into a "nice looking" dataframe like below (aligned properly of course)

ID  LocID   ProgID  Late    ProjID  NumInTeam
1557    335 12  288 55  5
1557    335 12  288 66  3
3058    777 62  20  62  7
3058    777 58  21  58  8
3058    777 38  15  38  18

What is the best way of doing this? Thanks.

Arun

Comment: Did you try pandas.read_json https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html?

Comment: I tried what was given there using all available options but could not get what I was looking for - I get the same thing as before.